# Separate rows on string & preserving original

Tags: r, regex, tidyr, data-cleaning

I'm working on a project where I want all permutations of specific strings. I'm using `tidyr::separate_rows` to split and duplicate on a specific string, but I want to preserve the original row.

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
temp <- tibble(raw_name = c("happy bank dba american bank and trust", " sohappy bank dba american bank"), clean_name = c("american bank and trust", "american bank"))
```

So here's what I'm doing now:

```
final <- temp %>%
    separate_rows(raw_name, sep = "dba")
```

Which loss my original rows. I've looked at the documentation, but there's no version of `.keep_all = TRUE` that I can find. Here is the result of the above `separate_rows`:

```
  raw_name                               clean_name             
  <chr>                                  <chr>                  
1 happy bank dba american bank and trust american bank and trust
2 " sohappy bank dba american bank"      american bank
```

My current solution is to create a new df with the offending observations, do the `separate_rows` and rbind the original rows. Here is my desired result:

```
raw_name                               clean_name             
  <chr>                                  <chr>                  
1 happy bank dba american bank and trust american bank and trust
2 " sohappy bank dba american bank"      american bank          
3 "happy bank "                          american bank and trust
4 " american bank and trust"             american bank and trust
5 " sohappy bank "                       american bank          
6 " american bank"                       american bank
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After separating the rows, we can bind with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
temp %>% 
  separate_rows(raw_name, sep="\\s*dba\\s*") %>%
  bind_rows(temp, .)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  raw_name                                 clean_name             
#* <chr>                                    <chr>                  
#1 "happy bank dba american bank and trust" american bank and trust
#2 " sohappy bank dba american bank"        american bank          
#3 "happy bank"                             american bank and trust
#4 "american bank and trust"                american bank and trust
#5 " sohappy bank"                          american bank          
#6 "american bank"                          american bank
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. Would you please give more context to the `\\s* \\s*` around dba? Is this just capturing extra spaces or is it doing something beyond that?

Comment: @Francisco the `*` implies zero or more spaces (`\\s`) ie. to capture the space before or after

Answer (score 0):

Based on @akrun answer, we can have another approach

```
temp <- data.frame(raw_name = c("happy bank dba american bank and trust", 
                            " sohappy bank dba american bank"), 
               clean_name = c("american bank and trust", "american bank"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

temp2 <- temp %>% 
  mutate(raw_name = strsplit(raw_name, "\\s*dba\\s*")) %>% 
  unnest(raw_name) %>% 
  bind_rows(temp)
```

## output

```
  raw_name                                 clean_name             
  <chr>                                    <chr>                  
1 "happy bank"                             american bank and trust
2 "american bank and trust"                american bank and trust
3 " sohappy bank"                          american bank          
4 "american bank"                          american bank          
5 "happy bank dba american bank and trust" american bank and trust
6 " sohappy bank dba american bank"        american bank
```

Update: If you want to remove white space in the beginning of string, you can try:

```
Library(stringr)
temp2$raw_name <- str_squish(temp2$raw_name)
output:
  raw_name                               clean_name             
  <chr>                                  <chr>                  
1 happy bank                             american bank and trust
2 american bank and trust                american bank and trust
3 sohappy bank                           american bank          
4 american bank                          american bank          
5 happy bank dba american bank and trust american bank and trust
6 sohappy bank dba american bank         american bank
```